# Are there areas of desert sands which experience blizzards?

Tags: meteorology, desert

Building off of another question I recently asked ([Is there sand in Antarctica?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14214/is-there-sand-in-antarctica)) I want to ask a broader question coming from the same motive described there.

Are there desert sands that experience blizzards? I know of places with sand that experience blizzards, for example certain beaches in the Adirondacks or Great Lakes of northeastern USA. But what about desert sands?

The other question identifies Antarctic desert sands, and a comment even notes that where Chicago is now was once covered in desert sands. The latter point made me realize though, do blizzards (snow storms with high winds, to be specific) occur in these sand dune areas? If yes, then are there numerous examples of where this occurs, or is it a somewhat rare thing?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you consider "desert sands".  For instance, Sand Mountain in Nevada https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand_Mountain_(Nevada) is an area of sand dunes in a desert, and occasionally experiences snowstorms that reach blizzard conditions.

Although most of the lower elevations are sagebrush steppe, there are other areas of sand (and dry lake beds &c) in the Great Basin, and the area experiences winter cold, occasional snow, and high winds.  I'd expect similar conditions in the Gobi Desert, though I have no first-hand experience: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobi_Desert

Comment: I know that the Gobi gets snow blown in from Siberia in winter because one of the unique things about the Mongolian Camel is their ability to eat it without getting frostbitten mouths.